# List of resources available for a given configuration on Slurm

Tags: slurm

Is there a command or way to get the available resources for a given configuration on Slurm?

For example, if I need the following configuration `--time=4-0 --mem 128G --node 1`, how can I get the list of available nodes on a cluster on Slurm?